# Trying to create a different unique key to query on

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has two fields that are a unique key, but the keys in this table I don't need because I need two other fields that are not included in this table (Jda_sourcing). I created a query that I think would give me what I need, but I'm not sure.  I ran and there are no errors, but wondering if this is the way go.

This is a long query, so I won't include everything.  I want the composite key to be BrandNum and site vendor. These columns are not in the Jda_sourcing Table. The Item is what is in common with both tables. I'm not sure if this is the way to go, so that is why I'm posting this question.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       item,
       source,
       dest
FROM [dq].[jda_sourcing] AS js
WHERE [item] IN (SELECT [item]
                 FROM [dq].[jda_udt_item_local]
                 WHERE
                     --EXISTS  
                     [u_brand] IN (SELECT TOP 100
                                          itm.u_brand AS BrandNum
                                   FROM (SELECT lnk.material,
                                                loc.plant,
                                                loc.storagelocation,
                                                lnk.purchasingstatus,
                                                lnk.sellingstatus,
                                                lnk.sitevendor,
                                                CASE WHEN ssc.material IS NOT NULL THEN 'SSC' ELSE 'DIRECT' END AS source
                                         FROM scm.sap_marc AS lnk
                                              JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                                                           loc AS plant,
                                                           RIGHT(location_id, 4) AS storagelocation,
                                                           loc_type
                                                    FROM dq.static_location
                                                    WHERE loc IS NOT NULL
                                                      AND loc_status = 'A'
                                                      AND loc_type = 'FWD') AS loc ON loc.plant = lnk.plant
                                              LEFT JOIN scm.sap_mard AS ssc ON ssc.plant = loc.plant
                                                                           AND ssc.material = lnk.material
                                                                           AND ssc.sscvalidfrom <= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                                                           AND ssc.sscvalidto >= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                              LEFT JOIN scm.sap_zdt_mm_source AS src ON src.plant = lnk.plant
                                                                                    AND src.material = lnk.material
                                                                                    AND (lnk.sitevendor = src.vendor
                                                                                      OR ssc.material IS NOT NULL
                                                                                      OR LEN(src.vendor) = 4)
                                                                                    AND src.validfromdate <= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                                                                    AND src.validtodate >= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                         WHERE lnk.purchasingstatus IN ('P', 'U', 'W')
                                           AND src.material IS NULL) AS msrc
                                        LEFT JOIN dq.jda_udt_item_local AS itm ON itm.item = msrc.material
                                        LEFT JOIN scm.sap_mara AS ssn ON ssn.material = msrc.material
                                                                     AND ssn.supercedeeffdate <= GETDATE()
                                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT item,
                                                          dest,
                                                          tier1,
                                                          gs_source,
                                                          supplier,
                                                          otc_status,
                                                          u_inco_term
                                                   FROM [flmir-jdasqldv1].scdq.dq.jda_sku_sourcing AS SKUSRC
                                                        JOIN [flmir-jdasqldv1].scdq.dq.jda_udt_loc AS LOC ON LOC.loc = SKUSRC.tier1
                                                   WHERE tier1 <> ''
                                        --and otc_status in ('AA','AH','IN','IF','IH') 
                                        ) AS lss ON lss.item = msrc.material
                                                AND lss.dest = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
                                        LEFT JOIN scm.ci_corpitem AS ci ON ci.item = msrc.material
                                        --left join [dq].[jda_sourcing]js on js.[item]=msrc.material 
                                        --and js.[dest]= cast(msrc.plant as varchar) + '-' + cast(msrc.storagelocation as varchar) 
                                        LEFT JOIN temp.lg_sourcing_xref AS lgs ON lgs.item = msrc.material
                                                                              AND lgs.plant = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar)
                                                                              AND lgs.sloc = CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
                                   WHERE ISNULL(itm.u_prod_class, 0) NOT IN (40, 85, 86, 94, 96, 99)
                                     AND ISNULL(itm.u_brand, 0) <> '9999'))
  AND LEN(source) = 13
GROUP BY item,
         source,
         dest
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*),
       item,
       source,
       dest
FROM [dq].[jda_sourcing] AS js
WHERE [item] IN (SELECT [material]
                 FROM [scm].[sap_marc]
                 WHERE
                     --EXISTS  
                     [sitevendor] IN (SELECT TOP 100
                                             msrc.sitevendor AS SiteVendor
                                      FROM (SELECT lnk.material,
                                                   loc.plant,
                                                   loc.storagelocation,
                                                   lnk.purchasingstatus,
                                                   lnk.sellingstatus,
                                                   lnk.sitevendor,
                                                   CASE WHEN ssc.material IS NOT NULL THEN 'SSC' ELSE 'DIRECT' END AS source
                                            FROM scm.sap_marc AS lnk
                                                 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                                                              loc AS plant,
                                                              RIGHT(location_id, 4) AS storagelocation,
                                                              loc_type
                                                       FROM dq.static_location
                                                       WHERE loc IS NOT NULL
                                                         AND loc_status = 'A'
                                                         AND loc_type = 'FWD') AS loc ON loc.plant = lnk.plant
                                                 LEFT JOIN scm.sap_mard AS ssc ON ssc.plant = loc.plant
                                                                              AND ssc.material = lnk.material
                                                                              AND ssc.sscvalidfrom <= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                                                              AND ssc.sscvalidto >= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                                 LEFT JOIN scm.sap_zdt_mm_source AS src ON src.plant = lnk.plant
                                                                                       AND src.material = lnk.material
                                                                                       AND (lnk.sitevendor = src.vendor
                                                                                         OR ssc.material IS NOT NULL
                                                                                         OR LEN(src.vendor) = 4)
                                                                                       AND src.validfromdate <= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                                                                       AND src.validtodate >= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                            WHERE lnk.purchasingstatus IN ('P', 'U', 'W')
                                              AND src.material IS NULL) AS msrc
                                           LEFT JOIN dq.jda_udt_item_local AS itm ON itm.item = msrc.material
                                           LEFT JOIN scm.sap_mara AS ssn ON ssn.material = msrc.material
                                                                        AND ssn.supercedeeffdate <= GETDATE()
                                           LEFT JOIN (SELECT item,
                                                             dest,
                                                             tier1,
                                                             gs_source,
                                                             supplier,
                                                             otc_status,
                                                             u_inco_term
                                                      FROM [flmir-jdasqldv1].scdq.dq.jda_sku_sourcing AS SKUSRC
                                                           JOIN [flmir-jdasqldv1].scdq.dq.jda_udt_loc AS LOC ON LOC.loc = SKUSRC.tier1
                                                      WHERE tier1 <> ''
                                           --and otc_status in ('AA','AH','IN','IF','IH') 
                                           ) AS lss ON lss.item = msrc.material
                                                   AND lss.dest = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
                                           LEFT JOIN scm.ci_corpitem AS ci ON ci.item = msrc.material
                                           --left join [dq].[jda_sourcing]js on js.[item]=msrc.material 
                                           --and js.[dest]= cast(msrc.plant as varchar) + '-' + cast(msrc.storagelocation as varchar) 
                                           LEFT JOIN temp.lg_sourcing_xref AS lgs ON lgs.item = msrc.material
                                                                                 AND lgs.plant = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar)
                                                                                 AND lgs.sloc = CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
                                      WHERE ISNULL(itm.u_prod_class, 0) NOT IN (40, 85, 86, 94, 96, 99)
                                        AND ISNULL(itm.u_brand, 0) <> '9999'))
  AND LEN(source) = 13
GROUP BY item,
         source,
         dest;
```

Comment: That query is incomplete. You have `FROM (SELECT )` Where's the rest of that statement (and the alias on the subquery)? Then you have an `AND` but no prior `WHERE`.

Comment: That's not really a lot to go on, without knowing the structures of all those objects in your query.

Comment: But what is the question? You posted a partial bit of sql but you don't actually ask anything other than a vague explanation of the requirements.

Comment: There is also 3 sets of parenthesis that aren't closed. That many nested subqueries though are going to be likely a performance killer.

Comment: i will post the whole query. I'll edit it.

Comment: No we have over 200 lines of sql that is not really formatted very well and still no explanation of what the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to get the sourcing from the Jda sourcing table by using the brand num and site vendor. I'm not sure if I'm being clear.

Comment: We can't see your screen and trying to decipher that query makes me want to take out my eyeballs and peel them. I notice you are casting things varchar a LOT in here without specifying the length. You should break that habit as it can cause lots of anguish. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length There is certainly a number of things here that are less than ideal. Using TOP 100 with no order by, it seems like you are storing dates as strings and doing comparisons....

Comment: yes, I see what you mean. Every casting should specify a length, otherwise, it will do its own assumption.

Answer (score 0):

With a little refactoring your code can be clearer -- like this:

Maybe this will also help to make your question clearer since you can reference the sub-queries by name?

```
WITH lss AS
(
  SELECT item,
         dest,
         tier1,
         gs_source,
         supplier,
         otc_status,
         u_inco_term
  FROM [flmir-jdasqldv1].scdq.dq.jda_sku_sourcing AS SKUSRC
  JOIN [flmir-jdasqldv1].scdq.dq.jda_udt_loc AS LOC ON LOC.loc = SKUSRC.tier1
  WHERE tier1 <> ''
), loc as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    loc AS plant,
    RIGHT(location_id, 4) AS storagelocation,
    loc_type
  FROM dq.static_location
  WHERE loc IS NOT NULL AND loc_status = 'A' AND loc_type = 'FWD'
), msrc AS
(
  SELECT lnk.material,
           loc.plant,
           loc.storagelocation,
           lnk.purchasingstatus,
           lnk.sellingstatus,
           lnk.sitevendor,
           CASE WHEN ssc.material IS NOT NULL THEN 'SSC' ELSE 'DIRECT' END AS source
    FROM scm.sap_marc AS lnk
    JOIN loc ON loc.plant = lnk.plant
    LEFT JOIN scm.sap_mard AS ssc ON ssc.plant = loc.plant
                                      AND ssc.material = lnk.material
                                      AND ssc.sscvalidfrom <= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                      AND ssc.sscvalidto >= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
    LEFT JOIN scm.sap_zdt_mm_source AS src ON src.plant = lnk.plant
                                               AND src.material = lnk.material
                                               AND (lnk.sitevendor = src.vendor
                                                 OR ssc.material IS NOT NULL
                                                 OR LEN(src.vendor) = 4)
                                               AND src.validfromdate <= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
                                               AND src.validtodate >= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)
    WHERE lnk.purchasingstatus IN ('P', 'U', 'W') AND src.material IS NULL
), t100brand AS
(
  SELECT TOP 100
           itm.u_brand AS BrandNum
  FROM  msrc
  LEFT JOIN dq.jda_udt_item_local AS itm ON itm.item = msrc.material
  LEFT JOIN scm.sap_mara AS ssn ON ssn.material = msrc.material
                                     AND ssn.supercedeeffdate <= GETDATE()
  LEFT JOIN  lss ON lss.item = msrc.material AND lss.dest = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
  LEFT JOIN scm.ci_corpitem AS ci ON ci.item = msrc.material
         --left join [dq].[jda_sourcing]js on js.[item]=msrc.material 
         --and js.[dest]= cast(msrc.plant as varchar) + '-' + cast(msrc.storagelocation as varchar) 
  LEFT JOIN temp.lg_sourcing_xref AS lgs ON lgs.item = msrc.material
                                               AND lgs.plant = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar)
                                               AND lgs.sloc = CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
  WHERE ISNULL(itm.u_prod_class, 0) NOT IN (40, 85, 86, 94, 96, 99)
      AND ISNULL(itm.u_brand, 0) <> '9999')
), t100branditem AS
(
  SELECT [item]
  FROM [dq].[jda_udt_item_local]
  JOIN t100brand t100 on u_brand = t100.u_brand)
), t100vender AS
(
  SELECT TOP 100
           msrc.sitevendor AS SiteVendor
  FROM msrc
  LEFT JOIN dq.jda_udt_item_local AS itm ON itm.item = msrc.material
  LEFT JOIN scm.sap_mara AS ssn ON ssn.material = msrc.material
                               AND ssn.supercedeeffdate <= GETDATE()
  LEFT JOIN lss ON lss.item = msrc.material
          AND lss.dest = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
  LEFT JOIN scm.ci_corpitem AS ci ON ci.item = msrc.material
  --left join [dq].[jda_sourcing]js on js.[item]=msrc.material 
  --and js.[dest]= cast(msrc.plant as varchar) + '-' + cast(msrc.storagelocation as varchar) 
  LEFT JOIN temp.lg_sourcing_xref AS lgs ON lgs.item = msrc.material
                                        AND lgs.plant = CAST(msrc.plant AS varchar)
                                        AND lgs.sloc = CAST(msrc.storagelocation AS varchar)
  WHERE ISNULL(itm.u_prod_class, 0) NOT IN (40, 85, 86, 94, 96, 99)
    AND ISNULL(itm.u_brand, 0) <> '9999')

), t100materialvendor as
(
  SELECT [material]
  FROM [scm].[sap_marc]
  join t100vender v on sitevendor = v.sitevendor  
  where LEN(source) = 13
)

    SELECT COUNT(*),
           item,
           source,
           dest
    FROM [dq].[jda_sourcing] AS js
    join t100branditem bi ON bi.item = js.item
    where LEN(source) = 13
    GROUP BY item, source, dest

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(*),
           item,
           source,
           dest
    FROM [dq].[jda_sourcing] AS js
    join t100materialvendor mv ON mv.material = js.item
    GROUP BY item, source, dest;
```

Comment: thank you. I'm reviewing it and I get an error because of invalid column name u_brand. I think it because none of the tables inside msrc has u-brand as a column. I checked all 3 tables, scm.sap_marc, scm.sap_mard and scm.sap_zdt_mm_source.

Comment: @RFC what table was it coming from in your original script?